# Error "Something unexpected went wrong with this url" in Outlook

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microsoft-outlook, http

Windows 10, Office 2016:

Clicking http links in Outlook I receive the error:

> Something unexpected went wrong with this url

The links do not open in the browser.

Additional symptoms are that, after installing an updated version of Waterfox (Firefox variant), there are two entries for Waterfox in the Default Apps Web Browser selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was reported useful to change the default browser to something else, then change it back to what you want.

You can refer to the thread discussed in Technet forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/36a3023b-1280-4c5d-b2ab-bde22a9e0994/outlook-2016-windows-10-something-unexpected-went-wrong-with-this-url-not-enough-storage-is?forum=outlook

Comment: I marked this as an answer because it contains the gist of the solution, but as it relies on a link for the relevant explanation it is not as comprehensive on its own as my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this error is that the entry selected in Default Apps for handling HTTP links is invalid.

You may also find that opening http links from elsewhere on the system, you'll receive a message "This app has been blocked by your system administrator".

Change the Web Browser entry in Default Apps, close and reopen Outlook, and the issues will go away.

In cases where there are duplicate entries in the Default Apps screen, select each in turn and try opening an http shortcut. If it opens successfully in the desired web browser, this same selection should open with the above error in Outlook.